# Small and free animated icons

Tags: icon

Anyone knows a good resource on the web with animated icons? Like animated pencil or something like that.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check: http://www.iconbazaar.com/animated/

Comment: uh, they are so ugly. :D

Comment: Holy 1998 Batman!